# How can i use Python 3rd party Package in UWP app of Windows10 IOT

Tags: python, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

How can i use Python 3rd party Package in UWP app of Windows10 IOT ?

When i import some lib, only lib that i can use is 'Windows10 IOT UWP Package', not normal python package.

so, is there any way to use 3rd party python lib on UWP enviroment?

Comment: Supposing you're using Raspberry Pi, you need to have an arm targeted python library in order to be referenced.